# C# Directory.GetFolder Order Folders And Set Them To List<> Without Losing Memory And Doing Additional Sort Operations

Tags: c#, .net, directoryinfo

just want know how to Order folders like they looking in my Explorer folder Sorted by name .. It's looks like :::

[image]

So i tried use this :::

```
 DirectoryInfo sourcreInfo = new DirectoryInfo(SourcePath);
                DirectoryInfo[] sourceFolders = sourcreInfo.GetDirectories().OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToArray();
```

but for sure it's not working ... not sorting and in addition it needs addition memmory ... imagine i have in my folder 1000 reports ...

soo ... here how i worked with this sourceFolders:: reportDir is just List

```
  foreach (DirectoryInfo report in sourceFolders)
                {
                  reportDir.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(report.Name)).ToString()));      
                }
```

Guys waiting for any proposition how to get Ordered by Name Directories ... To make this operation correctly .. :)

Really what in result i getting using DirectoryInfo ::::

[image]

I expected :: report1, report2 , report3 , report4 , report5 ....

by numbers, like shows in explorer picture

Comment: The results you posted *are* sorted, in the expected way for strings. `OrderBy` works, there's no if or but about it. What kind of ordering did you expect? Did you expect the string `report10` to appear after the string `report2`? That's not the normal sort order

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos bottom picture shows how my OrderBy works

Comment: The sort order you want to have is called "Natural Sort". It means that letters are compared as letters and numbers are compared as numbers. See linked question on how to use it in c#

Comment: @PampulKa which is the expected sort order for strings. `report10` comes before `report2`. The name is a *string*, not a number

Comment: Got it .. but i need by numbers really

Comment: Read the duplicate. What you ask for is called the natural sort order and is *not* exactly trivial. What if the numbers you care about appear in the middle of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `EnumerateDirectories`, like this:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\windows");
List<DirectoryInfo> subDirs = di.EnumerateDirectories().OrderBy(d => d.Name).ToList();
```

EDIT:
Ordering works and it will be like in your example, only a bit more efficient by using `EnumerateDirectories`. Ordering is done as text, not as numbers, so `report2` will always be after `report1` and `report11119`. So, if you want it to be ordered correctly, have it with leading zeros, like `report01`, `report02`...

To order by number, you'll have to do some tinkering like this:

Order by taking 6th letter from report name, convert it to integer and then sort.
In this case, you'll get exception if folder name is shorter than seven chars, if seventh or any following char isn't number (like in cases of folder names like `rep1`, `reports1`, `reporting` etc)

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\temp\\reports");
List<DirectoryInfo> subDirs = 
    di.EnumerateDirectories()
        .OrderBy(d => int.Parse(d.Name.Substring(6))).ToList();
```

Comment: Same Problem like in Picture , Really what in result i getting using DirectoryInfo ::::

Comment: @PampulKa the picture doesn't show any problem. The results are sorted

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so explain why name not sorted like in Explorer ... reportor1, reportor2, reportor3 ?

Comment: @PampulKa because Explorer isn't sorting the names in alphabetical order, it's using a natural sort order. If you check the duplicate you'll see that different Windows versions used slightly different ordering too

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you edit it and show how it must looks like in my example ?